# Mini cart product and cart page product order sequences does NOT match in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I tried,

in `catalog_category_view.xml` file

```
  <referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple reason: Mini cart: get array of last added items. The last item will be pushed at the top.

*\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart::getRecentItems()*

```
 foreach (array_reverse($this->getAllQuoteItems()) as $item) {
   ...... 
 }
```

We can write a Plugin to re-order the item in Mini cart.

> Vendor/MiniCart/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="item_cart_data" type="Vendor\MiniCart\Plugin\CustomerData\Cart"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/MiniCart/Plugin/CustomerData/Cart.php

```
/**
 * @param DataCart $subject
 * @param $result
 * @return mixed $result
 */
public function afterGetSectionData(DataCart $subject, $result)
{
    //Re-order the cart items
    $items = array_reverse($result['items']);
    $result['items'] = $items;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Create di.xml under YourModuleName/MiniCart/etc/frontend/ folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
    <plugin name="extra_data" type="YourModuleName\MiniCart\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**Step 2.** Create Cart.php under YourModuleName/MiniCart/Plugin/Checkout/CustomerData/ folder

```
<?php
namespace YourModuleName\MiniCart\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;

class Cart {
public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, array $result)
{        
    //Re-order the cart items
    $items = array_reverse($result['items']);
    $result['items'] = $items;
    return $result;
}
}
```

**Step 3.** Clear Cache and flush Cache

Hope it'll help you.